# jQuery Templates - How to check if template is already compiled and is in templates stack?

Tags: jquery, templates

I'm using official jQuery template plugin:
http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

I need some boolean check to know if template is already compiled.

Anyone knows how to check it?

Thanks ;)

**Update**

```
($.tmpl('thumbnail',data))
```

Should return false if there is no compiled template with name 'thumbnail' right?

Or it's a bug...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing to see if $.template['thumbnail'] is defined should be faster.